# How to get custom product attributes values using graphQl queries in magento 2.3?

Tags: product-attribute, custom, magento2.3.2, graphql

I want to get the values for custom product attribute in product details page.
I am using below **GrapgQl** query to get the values.
i am passing the name as the argument. How can i get the products attributes.

```
{
products(filter:{name: {eq: "Joust Duffle Bag"}}
                    ){
items{
  id
  sku
  special_price
  description{ html}
  short_description{ html}
  meta_title
  meta_keyword
  meta_description
  options_container
  type_id
  image{ url label }
  small_image{ url label }
  thumbnail{ url label }
  price{  
    regularPrice{
      amount{ 
        value
        currency
      }
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some searches we dont need any special query methods to retriew custom attributes.
We can just pass the custom attribute code to the query.

EX -  our custom attribute code is **publisher** just pass it in the query.

```
{
products(filter:{name: {eq: "Joust Duffle Bag"}}
                ){
items{
id
sku
publisher
price{  
regularPrice{
  amount{ 
    value
    currency
  }
}
}
}
}
}
```

to get the custom attribute values and label if it was the multiple select or select type refer [How to get product attribute value, label using GraphQl in Magento 2.3?](http://www.mujahidh.com/how-to-get-product-attribute-value-label-using-graphql-in-magento-2-3/)

Comment: but what about option and drop down attributes...
that's all just printing id only...

Comment: @prabhakaran7 for that you want to write a custom module.I explained this in this article http://www.mujahidh.com/how-to-get-product-attribute-value-label-using-graphql-in-magento-2-3/

Comment: this one is ok 
but what if i want in  product details page -(Product query)

Comment: custom attribute is already there but it's showing id in product query ....

Comment: @prabhakaran7 native graphql product query you cannot achieve it. based on the article try to do it in the custom method like passing the attribute id and get the lable value in product details page

Comment: for that you should pass custom graphql query along with product query.

Comment: Thanks a lot, man!

Comment: @IslamMurtazaev happy for sharing this :)

Answer (score 6):

For product attributes to be available in GraphQL, `is_user_defined` has to be true **AND** at least one of the following:

- `is_comparable`
- `is_filterable`
- `is_filterable_in_search`
- `is_visible_on_front`
- `used_in_product_listing`
- `used_for_sort_by`

**Reference:** `\Magento\CatalogGraphQl\Model\Resolver\Products\Attributes\Collection::getAttributes()`

---

Additionally, if the attributes should be *filterable* as well, at least one of the following must be true:

- (Attribute is `searchable` AND `visible_in_advanced_search`)
- attribute is "Used in Layered Navigation" (`is_filterable`)

And if the type is "Select", it must have options.

**Reference:** `\Magento\CatalogGraphQl\Model\Config\FilterAttributeReader::getFilterAttributes()`